# Angular app only loads on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I am building a wordpress site with a page that is an angular app. It was working until recently (and I can't recall which change broke it), but now the app does not load when I arrive at the page via a link (angular is loaded and the code snippet below processed, but nothing is logged), but it **does work** if I then refresh the page.

I've backed out all the real code to leave:

```
angular.module("af2015App", [])
.controller("TestCtrl", function() {
    console.log("test test");
});
```

And commented out everything in the HTML except

```
<div ng-app="af2015App" class="app">
    <p ng-controller="TestCtrl">Use the ...!</p>
</div>
```

I'm at a loss as to how to debug these circumstances. I'm **not** loading pages via AJAX.

Comment: As pointed out by @Arno_Geismar, you don't close div tag on this excerpt, can you post all relevant code ? How do you call angular on the document ?

Comment: It is loaded by WordPress at the end of the body. As i said the question is what to look for when coming via a link to the page rather than when doing a refresh

Comment: Just try calling Angular in the <head> element (with wp_head() if you use wordpress).

Comment: In my case i had to switch from chrome to mozila or edge and works nickel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your ideas everyone. I had another go at debugging and discovered that, even after turning off the script tag with angular, angular was still present. That gave me the idea to look at Batarang and, after deactivating that, all is working again. Perhaps this answer will help someone someday. Needless to say I don't know what the underlying problem was.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this plunker 
[working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BdqopYYWtamMlSSiQY1c?p=preview)

they only thing I can think of when looking at your code is that you are not closing your div tag
altough that is probably just an edit mistake
otherwise move your ng-app definition to your html tag

```
    <html ng-app="af2015App">
      <head> 
         //make sure your scripts are loaded correctly

         <script src="path/to/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="path/to/app.js"></script>
         <script src="path/to/controller.js"></script>
      </head>
        <div class="app">
            <p ng-controller="TestCtrl">Use the ...!</p>
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I just didn't bother including the `div` in the snippet - it is there. I tried moving to html tag but that didn't change anything. I'm so frustrated. I suspect I wil have to restart from the beginning and add things 1 by 1

Comment: How do you call angular in your document ?

Comment: @Simon H In my document I add a script tag i updated my answer

Comment: You missed the body tag ;)